# how to store base64 encoded string in solr and search using solr query with normal text

Tags: elasticsearch, solr

I am using `solr` for data indexing for storing some of field. I am using field as `<field name="Content" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>`, the data is in base64 encoded format.

For the field content I want to search in that data using keywords which are in plain text. By decoding base64 I can find that keyword in the content.
(like elastic search with attachment field type where we have to pass base64 encoded data and we can search in that data)

I'm using query on solr browser but not able to find the result:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/collection/select?q=Content%3A*English*&wt=json&indent=true
```

Answer (score 0):

Solr does not know your content is base64. Furthermore, *type=string* is not tokenized.

So, you need to do some pre-processing. Probably as a custom element somewhere. If you just want to search the field, you probably don't need to store it (just index) and could have a custom UpdateRequestProcessor that does base64 decoding.

If you want to actually store the field, then the processing needs to happen as the very first step of the indexing pipeline. So you need a custom CharacterFilter before you do tokenization.

Unfortunately, neither component exists in the base distribution right now. You would have to code it in Java or - if you are using UpdateRequestProcessor - [in Javascript](http://www.solr-start.com/javadoc/solr-lucene/org/apache/solr/update/processor/StatelessScriptUpdateProcessorFactory.html).

Comment: How do i use updaterequestprocessor provide me some links to understand it.Also i had heard about solr attachment how should i use it with my requirement

Comment: Solr Reference Guide has [the information](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Update+Request+Processors). You can also find the full list of the URPs on [the Solr Start website](http://www.solr-start.com/info/update-request-processors/). Some of the shipped examples include various URP chains to check out as well.

Comment: I also have to process attachments with all details so should i use apache solr attachment ( like in elastic search we are using external plugin mapper attachment) how should i do with solr, I had gone through the https://docs.acquia.com/acquia-search/attachments but nat able to get follong configration chang with my solr browser